# Catch HTTP error when passing JQuery .get() result to variable

Tags: jquery

The following code successfully performs a `GET` request to the `timeout.ashx` file if the user is logged in:

```
    function StillHereClicked() {
        var loadedResult;
        $.get("/timeout.ashx", function (loadedResult) {
            if (loadedResult == 'Extended') {
                // stay logged in (code removed for brevity)
            } else {
                LogOut();
            }
        }, 'text');
    }
```

However, should the user's session get terminated for any reason, the `GET` request throws a `401 Unauthorized` exception in the browser.

Can anyone please help me catch *any* error (401, 404 etc) that might occur here, and simply logout the user in every case?  If `timeout.ashx` returns *anything* other than a string with value `'Extended'`, then the user should be logged out.

I tried to follow the [.get() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/sig2=tklZHJBj8cJ5kam2PAfjPw), but I can't figure out the syntax as they appear to be dealing with multiple callbacks, and other examples seem to complicate matters with AJAX and MVC added on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually, despite most examples online using deprecated code...
[.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) has all the functionality required.

```
    function StillHereClicked() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/timeout.ashx",
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data == "Extended") {
                // stay logged in (code removed for brevity)
            } else {
                LogOut();
            }
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, textStatus) {
            LogOut();
        });
    }
```